# How do I ask users to choose data in intelliJ GUI Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ to create a relatively simple form that does the data mining given data.

So obviously, I want to get **data** from the user. How can I bind such data (which will be quite big) through this GUI form? In JetBrains, they mentioned something about [Data Binding Wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/data-binding-wizard.html) But I am not sure if this is what I really want.

What I want is to have a something that finds certain data from user's computer. How can I find a form that binds data from user's computer and further operates data mining?

I am trying to do something like what WEKA does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is to use a [File Chooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).